# Synthesize a case expression from a case object symbol

Tags: scala-macros

Consider the following definition:

```scala
case object Obj
```

I’d like to write a macro synthesizing the following case expression:

```scala
case Obj => Obj
```

I tried the following:

```scala
cq"`${s.name}` => ${s.name}"
```

Where `s` is the Symbol of the case object `Obj`, but I get the following compile error after expansion:

```
not found: type Obj
```

When using the `-Ymacro-debug-lite` option the expanded code looks like the following:

```
case Obj => Obj
```

What’s the correct way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Looks like a quasiquote issue. I've pinged Denys.

Comment: It's definitely a bug but it looks like it was fixed in 2.11 https://gist.github.com/densh/f3e94af120eea94b65a5. Paradise plugin is a bit behind atm. There is a plan to backport latest fixes some time around 2.11 release.